# Regional Settings in My Site

Tags: my-site, administration, 2007, localization

What is the difference between the below two steps to change the "Regional Settings" in My Site?

1. Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Regional settings -> Locale
2. My Settings -> My Regional Settings -> Locale (Uncheck the option "Always follow web settings")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every My site is a site collection. Site collection owner can change the default regional settings as (s)he pleases because there are parts of my site that could be made public like Shared or public documents. Although it might not be used heavily it is good to have consistent options across site collections.

Comment: do you mean to say that both the steps are equivalent ?

Comment: It could produce the same effect but these are not the same. The first option changes Regional Settings for entire site collection, and the second option changes your regional settings.